# Open big file txt (with) - error process_lines

Tags: python, text, with-statement

I am trying to read a big file in python.

```py
with open("some_big_file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        process_lines(line)
```

but i get this error:

NameError: name 'process_lines' is not defined

Comment: ha where is your `def process_lines(line)` function/method? it has nothing to do with the opening of the file but with the processing of it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
with open("some_big_file.txt") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        print(line)
```

This will output your file by lines. Then, you seem to not have function `process_lines`, so implement it.